# Checking a topology on a set is indeed a topology using munkres terminology.

Tags: general-topology

here is the question and my work:
[image]

IS this a correct solution? I still not sure about proving the intersection is in the topology.

Comment: Your proof is not correct. Indeed, there is no condition on the basis saying that it is closed under finite intersections. I suggest you to check a simpler thing: try to prove that for all $U,V \in \Bbb{T}$ necessarily $U \cap V\in \Bbb{T}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote,

> Let $$B=\bigcap_{i=1}^n B_i\implies x\in B\subseteq \bigcap_{i=1}^n U_i\implies \bigcap_{i=1}^n U_i\in\mathcal{T}\tag{1}$$

But the gap in the argument is that you haven't shown that $B$ is indeed a basis element. If you can't show this then the second implication doesn't follow logically. So, your proof is incorrect as [Crostul](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/160300/crostul) said.

However, this is not a very serious problem and you can easily overcome it by proving the following claim,

> **Claim.** There exists $B\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $(1)$ holds.
>
> *Hint for the Proof.* Use the result that if $B_1,B_2\in\mathcal{B}$ and $x\in B_1\cap B_2$ then there exists $B_3\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B_3\subseteq B_1,B_2$ and apply Principle of Mathematical Induction.